Как убрать синее выделение элемента Listbox
Когда выбираю элемент в листбоксе, он выделяется синим. Мне нужно это убрать и изменять Background кнопки.
Я понимаю что это нужно делать с помощью стилей, но как именно это сделать я не представляю, подскажите пожалуйста!
Вот мой листбокс в разметке:
<ListBox x:Name="SelectGame" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#272734" SelectionChanged="SelectGame_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Border CornerRadius="7" Width="55" Height="52" Background="#35354C">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="48" Height="48"/>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="#D4D4E5" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

Заранее спасибо!

Переопределите ItemContainerStyle задав там нужные значения.

@EvgeniyZ Как я и написал ранее, я знаю с помощью чего мне достичь результата, а именно с помощью стилей. Однако я не знаю "значений", которые нужно в стилях прописывать, чтобы убрать эту подсветку

Также нашел где-то в интернете что можно прописать "ControlTemplate". Кто-то знает что это и поможет ли в этом случае?

Ну вам нужно что? Сменить задний фон выделения, так? Задний фон это что? Правильно Background. Теперь вопрос, задний фон чего надо менять? По умолчанию, он зашит в системные ресурсы и так просто вы его вряд-ли поменяете, а значит, самое простое будет переопределить шаблон (Template). Ну и естественно триггеры, которые меняют значения. В итоге получаем что-то такое, ну а дальше уже полет фантазии... Если для вас и это не понятно, то советую начать с более простых задач, познать азы XAML и C#, иначе так и будете дальше тупо копировать код...

Если вам надо вообще убрать выделение, то ListBox вообще не ваш случай, ибо тут больше подойдет простой ItemsControl.

Вот теперь очень даже понятно, спасибо.
